can I make the phone's operations run on the user's side?
I decided to start writing code for a bot that will send messages to chats. It works as follows:
Due to the fact that messages should be sent by the user, and not by the bot, the bot requests the api_id and api_hash necessary for the telethon library to connect to the account.
I made it so that the bot asks the user for a phone number, after which the phone starts and the bot transmits it to the telethon so that all this happens on the user's side. However, I couldn't do it with the authentication code, because to get the authentication code, you need a login attempt, which must be made by a telethon.
Therefore, the phone requests an authentication code on the owner's side.
Is it possible to make this happen on the user's side, like with a phone number?
import telebot
import asyncio
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Данные для бота
bot_token = ''  
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

# Хранилище данных пользователей
user_data = {}

# Пул потоков для асинхронных задач
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

class TelegramBotHandler:
    def __init__(self, user_id, api_id, api_hash, phone_number):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.api_id = api_id
        self.api_hash = api_hash
        self.phone_number = phone_number
        self.phone_code_hash = None
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.client = TelegramClient(StringSession(), api_id, api_hash)

    def start(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        try:
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self.send_code_request())
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Running asyncio loop failed for user {self.user_id}: {e}")

    async def send_code_request(self):
        logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: In send_code_request function")
        try:
            await self.client.connect()
            logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Connected to Telegram client")

            if not await self.client.is_user_authorized():
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Sending code request")
                result = await self.client.send_code_request(self.phone_number)
                self.phone_code_hash = result.phone_code_hash

                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Code sent to phone {self.phone_number}, hash: {result.phone_code_hash}")
                bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Пожалуйста, введите код, который вы получили от Telegram.")
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Requested Telegram code from user")
            else:
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Already authorized")
        except errors.FloodWaitError as e:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], f"Слишком много запросов. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова через {e.seconds} секунд.")
            logger.error(f"User {self.user_id}: FloodWaitError, wait for {e.seconds} seconds")
        except errors.PhoneNumberInvalidError:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Номер телефона неправильный. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.")
            logger.error(f"User {self.user_id}: PhoneNumberInvalidError")
        except Exception as e:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], f"Произошла ошибка при отправке кода: {e}")
            logger.error(f"User {self.user_id}: Error sending code: {e}")

    async def complete_authorization(self, code):
        logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: In complete_authorization function with code {code}")
        try:
            if not await self.client.is_user_authorized():
                await self.client.sign_in(phone=self.phone_number, code=code, phone_code_hash=self.phone_code_hash)
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Signed in successfully with code {code}")

                bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Вы успешно авторизованы! Теперь вы можете отправлять сообщения через бота.")
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Authorization completed")
            else:
                logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Already authorized")
        except errors.SessionPasswordNeededError:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Требуется двухфакторная аутентификация. Пожалуйста, введите ваш пароль.")
            logger.info(f"User {self.user_id}: Two-factor authentication needed")
        except errors.CodeInvalidError:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Введенный код неверен. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.")
            logger.warning(f"User {self.user_id}: Invalid code entered")
        except errors.PhoneCodeExpiredError:
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], "Код истек. Я повторно отправлю вам новый код.")
            logger.warning(f"User {self.user_id}: Phone code expired, sending new code")
            await self.send_code_request()
        except Exception as e:
            import traceback
            error_details = traceback.format_exc()
            bot.reply_to(user_data[self.user_id]['message'], f"Произошла ошибка при авторизации: {e}")
            logger.error(f"User {self.user_id}: Authorization error: {e}\n{error_details}")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Command /start triggered")
    bot.reply_to(message, "Здравствуйте! Для начала работы, пожалуйста, введите ваш API ID.")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_api_id)

def get_api_id(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: In get_api_id function")
    try:
        user_data[user_id] = {'api_id': int(message.text)}
        bot.reply_to(message, "Введите ваш API Hash.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_api_hash)
        logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Received API ID: {message.text}")
    except ValueError:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Некорректный API ID. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_api_id)
        logger.warning(f"User {user_id}: Incorrect API ID entered")

def get_api_hash(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: In get_api_hash function")
    user_data[user_id]['api_hash'] = message.text
    bot.reply_to(message, "Введите ваш номер телефона в формате +1234567890.")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_phone_number)
    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Received API Hash: {message.text}")

def get_phone_number(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: In get_phone_number function")
    user_data[user_id]['phone_number'] = message.text
    user_data[user_id]['message'] = message

    bot.reply_to(message, "Отлично! Теперь подождите немного, пока я отправлю код на ваш телефон.")

    api_id = user_data[user_id]['api_id']
    api_hash = user_data[user_id]['api_hash']
    phone_number = user_data[user_id]['phone_number']

    logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Sending code request to phone {phone_number}")

    handler = TelegramBotHandler(user_id, api_id, api_hash, phone_number)
    user_data[user_id]['handler'] = handler
    executor.submit(handler.start)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['code'])
def receive_code(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    try:
        code = message.text.split()[1]
        handler = user_data[user_id]['handler']

        logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Received code {code} and starting authorization")
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(handler.complete_authorization(code), handler.loop)

        # Optionally, block until the authorization is complete
        future.result(timeout=600)
        logger.info(f"User {user_id}: Authorization completed successfully")
    except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуйста, введите команду /code <ваш код>")
        logger.warning(f"User {user_id}: Failed to receive code, incorrect format or missing handler: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        error_details = traceback.format_exc()
        bot.reply_to(message, f"Произошла ошибка при авторизации: {e}")
        logger.error(f"User {user_id}: Authorization error: {e}\n{error_details}")

# Запуск бота
logger.info("Starting bot polling")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

I want telethon to have a direct connection with the client

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
